# carrierwave sinatra model id as storage dir

Tags: sinatra, carrierwave

How would I create the following scenario that rails can provide for carrierwave, using sinatra:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

... being able to store an avatar under a directory named using the model ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have checked the wiki:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-a-fast-lookup-able-storage-directory-structure